# Problem with .htaccess file and exclude command

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a simple .htaccess which redirect non www to www domain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I need to do is to exclude the IP calling from this redirect.

In other words I need that if someone call site by IP then it won't be redirected to www domain, it will call the IP itself and visitor can navigate all the site links without the 301 redirect. This means he will still navigate the site through the IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It looks to see if the host does not start with www and if so it redirects to the www URL.  It won't match the IP address or any other subdomains (i.e. test.example.com)

Comment: its not working at it all when removed the www from the first condition

Comment: no i didn't and once i did it back to work normally thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome, it is very close to what you had, except it is looking to see that the host begins with yoursite.com and if so it will rewrite to www.  The `!` means not, so we removed the not check and are just looking to match ^yoursite.com$ and nothing else.